# Entity Relationship Diagram: Composition of primary and foreign keys

Tags: foreign-keys, primary-key, entity-relationship

I have defined the following tables with their attributes:

```
Table A)    Table B)    Table C)
- ID        - ID        - ID1
- Name      - xxx       - ID2
- Address   - yyy       - zzz
                        - ...
                        - ...
```

I have two questions:

1) In `Table A)`, `ID` is my primary key. The `ID` attribute in `Table A)` and `Table B)` are the same and I am not sure if in `Table B)` `ID` can be used as a primary and foreign key? Apparently, `ID` is also a primary key in `Table B)` but at the same time a foreign key for `Table A)`. Is that allowed?

2) In `Table C)` I need both attributes `ID1` and `ID2`. None of the two by itself is a primary but they ned the attribute `zzz` to be. However, the two attributes `ID1` and `ID2` are more or less interchangeable so that I have the possibility to create two different primary keys: 1) `ID1` + `zzz` OR 2) `ID2` + `zzz`. I am not sure if it matters which key to choose or if this scenario is allowed at all. Or is the primary key in this particular case the combination of all 3 attributes `ID1`, `ID2` and `zzz`?

Answer (score 0):

1. If ID in A and B is the same then you can merge the two tables and put same ID:

   ```
   Table AB)
   -ID
   -name
   -address
   -xxx
   -yyy
   ```

   so ID should not be the same...
2. You can use the primary key as combination of ID1 and ID2